# Send SMS through UIAlertView

Tags: ios, objective-c, sms, uialertview

I work for a roadside service and I have an app I made that will text me the user's location, that way I can find them easier. Right now I have it where you click the location button, it brings up a text message view with my number and their location in the body already set. All they have to do is send the text message. But as we all know, when something what may seem easy to us, it can be hard to do for others, especially for the elderly and technically challenged. So a lot of times I have to tell them how to do it, still easier than telling them how to share their location through Apple Maps.

So I was wondering if there was a way that I could put a `UIAlertView` that says "Share your location with .... through text message?". And if they hit yes or send, it will send the text for them. I know Apple won't let you send SMS without the user so you can't spam their contacts, but what if they give you permission through a `UIAlertView`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apple **does not allow** workarounds like this for suppressing the screen for SMS sending.

The most you can do is displaying an alert view that describes what the user should do on the message sending screen (pressing the round button in the bottom right corner etc.)

Comment: That's what I was pretty sure of, but figured it was worth a shot to see. Thanks!

Comment: @JohnKern If you like the answer, upvote it (by clicking on the ▲). If it answered your question, please click on the ✓